# How to get ongoing index in nested v-for loops

Tags: vue.js, indexing, vuejs2

I have some nested loops. The parent component loops a child component, the child component loops a grandchild component.

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child" :v-for="(child, childindex) in children">
      <div class="grandchild" :v-for="(grandchild, grandchildindex) in grandchildren">
         Some Stuff
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The index would give me something like

```
Child 0
   Grandchild 0
   Grandchild 1
Child 1
   Grandchild 0
   Grandchild 1
   Grandchild 2
```

and so on.

What I need however is this:

```
Child 0
   Grandchild 0
   Grandchild 1
Child 1
   Grandchild 2
   Grandchild 3
   Grandchild 4
```

So how can i get the grandchild index ongoing?

Answer (score 1):

To get a "global" grandchild index, you will need to know how many grandchildren were in all of the previous children, and then increment that number by the current grandchild index.

Although a bit ugly, the following code should work:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child" :v-for="(child, childindex) in children">
      <div class="grandchild" :v-for="(grandchild, grandchildindex) in child.grandchildren">
         Current global grandchild index:
        {{ children.slice(0, childindex)
                   .reduce((total, ch)=>total+=ch.grandchildren.length, 0)
                   + grandchildindex }}
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The relevant code (with comments):

```
// Get an array of all the previous children.
children.slice(0, childindex)
// Calculate the total length of all their grandchildren.
.reduce((total, ch)=>total+=ch.grandchildren.length, 0)
// Add the "current" grandchild index to it.
+ grandchildindex
```

Comment: Does not work if children / grandchildren are objects and not arrays